# Want to search in String if there is any special characters in it

Tags: java, regex

I want to search any special char in java string.
here is my code

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("hgbs!hf862376");
    boolean b = m.matches();

    if (b == true)
       System.out.println("sp. character is there");
```

But this is not working.
Can any one suggest correct Regex for this.
I want to allowed only a-z,A-Z and 0-1.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you accept any answers to any of your questions?

Answer (score 3):

`.*[^a-zA-Z0-9 ].*` instead of `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]`

^ within character class (i.e. square brackets) mean negation, so any but the characters listed. If not within character class, ^ means the beggining of the string.
Also you need to match anything before or after the special character.
So your original regex would have matched only strings that have a single letter among `a-zA-Z0-9`.

Comment: Thanx for your prompt response.I had try for this also, But still it's not working

Comment: oh I see - you need to match everything before and after the special character - I edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDocs:

- `Matcher.matches()` attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.
- `Matcher.find()` scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

You should use `Matcher.find()` is you're looking for some substring (even one character) which matches certain rules like not being alphanumerical.

Or you could use `Matcher.matches()`, but then the regular expression pattern should be `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+`, meaning you want a match if the string consists only of valid characters. If any other character appears then matches() will return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("hgbs!hf862376");
boolean b = m.matches(); // looking for no special characters

if (!b) {
    System.out.println("sp. character is there");
}
```