# Check special symbol in String

Tags: java, regex

I am looking how can I match special symbol with regex.

**For example:**

`#` - should return true;

`ERROR:#` - should return true;

`#dakfj` - should return true;

I tried this one, but it's not working properly:

`System.out.println("aaa#aaa".matches("#+"));`

Comment: .+#.+ is what you need

Comment: @TheLostMind, yes thanx. Or also simply use contains

Comment: also for handle first case it should be like .*#+.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, matches matches the whole string, so you should use `".*#+.*"`

Comment: `".#+."` doesn't match ANY of the three example Strings in the question.

Comment: Sorry, it was reformatted by SO. I marked it as code...

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think to check that.  My apologies.  I removed my downvote.  (By the way, you don't need the `+`)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use contains method of String
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `matches`, as this tests to match the *entire string*.

Use `find` instead: [Want to search in String if there is any special characters in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383136/want-to-search-in-string-if-there-is-any-special-characters-in-it#6383179)

Comment: So You found a duplicate (thanks), why don't you vote to close as dup?